# Unable to load Pickled Glove 840b 300d in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, nlp, data-science, kaggle

```
%%time

glove_embeddings = np.load('https://www.kaggle.com/code/authman/pickled-glove-840b-300d', allow_pickle=True)
fasttext_embeddings = np.load('../input/pickled-crawl300d2m-for-kernel-competitions/crawl-300d-2M.pkl', allow_pickle=True)
```

Getting error :

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'https://www.kaggle.com/code/authman/pickled-glove-840b-300d'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The external website from the Kaggle link shows a 404 error message, so there is no file available under that URL. Try to log in into Kaggle, go to this URL: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/authman/pickled-glove840b300d-for-10sec-loading, download the file manually and then use a local path in your code as you did for fasttext. Or you download the zipped file from the official website (https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) and pickle it yourself.